# SQL Server 2012 Filtering Results Based on One Table and Appending Info

Tags: sql

I've been trying to search for a similar query on stackoverflow to modify to get what I need but I can't seem to get it right.  I hope someone here can help.

I have two tables located in two different databases.  Both databases are configured on the same server. Table 1 called 'DiscreteLive' and located in Database 'Runtime'.  Table 2 is called 'v_DiscreteHistory' and located in Database 'WWALMDB'.

They have the following fields

### DiscreteLive

Tagname (type String)

Value (type Integer --> can only ever be 1 or 0)

### 'v_DiscreteHistory'

Tagname (type String)

Value (type String --> can only ever be true of false)

EventStamp (type datetime)

Description (type String)

The 'DiscreteLive' table can only ever have one unique tagname line.  An external software will overwrite to each tagname's corresponding Value field.  It's basically showing the live values of the system. Example shown below.  For example, you would never find Device1.Commfail twice in this table.

Device1.Commfail
Device1.Auto
Device1.Man
Device2.Commfail
Device2.Auto
Device2.Man
Device3.Commfail
Device3.Auto
Device3.Man
Device4.commfail
Device4.Auto
Device4.Man
Device5.Commfail
Device5.Auto
Device5.Man

etc.

The 'v_DiscreteHistory' table is the history of the specific tag.  There can be multiple entries of the same tag along with its Description and EventStamp (Time the even happened).

What I'm trying to do is to filter out the 'DiscreteLive' table to show only the tag values where the tagname is a %.CommFail and the Value is 1.  Then I would like to take the result of that initial query and attach the latest EventStamp and Description for those tags in the initial query from 'v_DiscreteHistory'.

Not sure if this can be done.  Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: show us what you have so far.

Comment: EventStamp is a datetime that is stored as a string?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server: This might be what you are looking for

```
SELECT 
    D.TagName
   ,D.Value
   ,V.Tagname
   ,V.Value,V.EventStamp
   ,V.Description 
   ,MAX(V.EventStamp) AS 'LatestDate'
FROM 
    SERVER.Runtime.dbo.DiscreteHistory D
INNER JOIN 
    SERVER.WWALMDB.dbo.v_DiscreteHistory V
    ON 
    D.Tagname = V.Tagname
WHERE 
    D.Value = 1 
    AND 
    V.Value LIKE '%.CommFail'
GROUP BY
    D.TagName
   ,D.Value
   ,V.Tagname
   ,V.Value,V.EventStamp
   ,V.Description
```

Comment: If however, he has stored the date as a string instead of a datetime, the max may not work correctly given that string sorting (to get the max) is different than date sorting.  You might need code to cast the data to datetime. Of course in this particular case the correct thing to do would be to fix the database as it is generally an extremely poor idea to store dates as varchar. But we can't always control database structures.  Also why is the aggregate in the group by?

Comment: Oops on the Aggregate in the Group By....I copied and pasted the select clause hastily

Comment: Whoop sorry guys,  I just rechecked the event stamp.  The event stamp is actually stored as DateTime.

Comment: @tranh2 Was this the answer you were looking for?  I updated answer to meet `DATETIME` metadata requirements